# dependency between binaries with cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project with two binaries, `foo` and `bar`. `foo` runs `bar` as a subprocess. If I change the source code for `bar` and then run `cargo run --bin foo`, I would like `bar` to be automatically rebuilt, but by default it is not. Is there a convenient/standard way to arrange this, or do I have to always run `cargo build --bin bar && cargo run --bin foo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Depend on the binary of another workspace package being built by cargo](/q/65240040/2189130) The answer is what you're already doing unfortunately. From the comments this is not supported, a RFC was created but doesn't look like much has progressed there.